# Load CSS in local in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

i try to load in WebView a code HTML with CSS, in local. the file CSS is storage in sdcard0/Style/Template.css. Html code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Template.css" />
```

Java code is:

```
            webView.loadData(source, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Not works.. i can't use Asset folder, there is any solution?

Comment: where is the html file located in relative to this css file? the way you wrote it, the html file itself should be located next to the style folder, otherwise it wont find it

Comment: yes folder Style and file Template.css is in the correct Path

Comment: the html file, where is it? is it near the style folder?

Comment: yes of course is in the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using link href file ?

Comment: yes i try.. if i use Chrome it works, but in the webView no!.. Chrome use the path file:///sdcard/.../index.html

Comment: "file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "Style/Template.css" alter your html at runtime using replace